# How to fix the " Debugger speedups using cython not found" in Eclipse+Pydev?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

this is my first post, I started to setup my IDE (Eclipse+Pydev). With the last version of Eclipse I face with this warning:

> Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/home/claudio/anaconda3/envs/Py3-11-3/bin/python" "/home/claudio/Software/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203/pysrc/setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace

I installed Python 3.11.3 from source and I created a virtual environment that I would like to use as interpreter.

I'm not able to fix it. I tried to run in my terminal the code:

> "/home/claudio/anaconda3/envs/Py3-11-3/bin/python" "/home/claudio/Software/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_10.1.4.202304151203/pysrc/setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace

but it doesn't work, I'm working on Debian 11.

Is there any package missing in my venv? How can I check it?
If I use the python installation of Debian by running the previous code the warning message does not appear, so the problem is in my virtual environment but I'm not able to recognize it.

Thank you in advance.

Claudio

Comment: What do you mean by, "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I runned the command "/home/claudio...pysrc/setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace, but I get the message about debugger speedup using cython not found. If I do the same, but using a virtual enviroment created starting from python installation of Debian all works. It doesn't work with the installation of Python 3.11.3 that I did by following the Python user guide. I hope that it is more clear, this is my first time with Eclipse. Thank you.